# BSOD due to DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)

Tags: windows, windows-10

I've been suffering from BSOD due to **DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE(9f)** maybe for **2 years**..

The BSOD happens well when I run AVD(Android Virtual Device) on Android Studio.
Especially it happens more frequently when I do some SMS receive test on the AVD.

I really want to know what occurs the BSOD so I installed WinDBG.
Some logs from dump are below:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.18362.1 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [c:\dump\memory.dmp]
Kernel Bitmap Dump File: Kernel address space is available, User address space may not be available.


************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 18362 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff802`17c00000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff802`180475b0
Debug session time: Mon Sep 16 23:48:01.342 2019 (UTC + 9:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:05:27.243
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
....................
Loading User Symbols

Loading unloaded module list
.............
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
6: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffff85048ca4e570, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: fffff9091dc7f7b0, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffff85048f7669a0, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------

Implicit thread is now ffff8504`8aad1040

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1


PROCESSES_ANALYSIS: 1

SERVICE_ANALYSIS: 1

STACKHASH_ANALYSIS: 1

TIMELINE_ANALYSIS: 1


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 401

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Notebook                        

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  N85_N87,HJ,HJ1,HK1

SYSTEM_SKU:  Not Applicable                  

SYSTEM_VERSION:  Not Applicable                  

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  1.05.10

BIOS_DATE:  03/23/2017

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Notebook                        

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  N85_N87,HJ,HJ1,HK1

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  Not Applicable                  

DUMP_TYPE:  1

BUGCHECK_P1: 3

BUGCHECK_P2: ffff85048ca4e570

BUGCHECK_P3: fffff9091dc7f7b0

BUGCHECK_P4: ffff85048f7669a0

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

FAULTING_THREAD:  ffff85048aad1040

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: af8

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 9e

CPU_STEPPING: 9

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,9e,9,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 8E'00000000 (cache) 8E'00000000 (init)

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DESKTOP-ER8PAC6

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  09-17-2019 01:11:08.0762

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.18362.1 amd64fre

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  fffff8023182bb48 -- (.exr 0xfffff8023182bb48)
ExceptionAddress: 4ba89f8800004ba4
   ExceptionCode: d08f8b48
  ExceptionFlags: 8b000024
NumberParameters: -1992032256
   Parameter[0]: 8b451774c9854800
   Parameter[1]: 04f833e8d48b41c5
   Parameter[2]: 000024d08f8b4800
   Parameter[3]: 8f8b480004f767e8
   Parameter[4]: 44cd8b4500001078
   Parameter[5]: 4120247c8844c68b
   Parameter[6]: 4890ff018b48d48b
   Parameter[7]: 0001759f38000002
   Parameter[8]: 0875ff8445547400
   Parameter[9]: fffaea98e8cf8b48
   Parameter[10]: 48000024c08f8b48
   Parameter[11]: 75805d383674c985
   Parameter[12]: 90ffd233018b480b
   Parameter[13]: 9670878b000001b8
   Parameter[14]: c43b41c42b410000

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff802318f8377 to fffff802318ec9e0

BAD_STACK_POINTER:  fffff8021bca3238

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff802`1bca3238 fffff802`318f8377 : ffff8504`913e7000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`0008715c : nvlddmkm+0x1cc9e0
fffff802`1bca3240 fffff802`318f84a8 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nvlddmkm+0x1d8377
fffff802`1bca32b0 fffff802`31b83afc : 00000000`00000000 ffffd04c`ec2032a0 fffff802`1bca3500 fffff802`1bca33e0 : nvlddmkm+0x1d84a8
fffff802`1bca32f0 fffff802`31b9462b : ffff8504`910ae7a0 ffff8504`910ae7a0 ffff8504`913e7000 00000000`02000068 : nvlddmkm+0x463afc
fffff802`1bca3330 fffff802`31b937d1 : 00000000`00000100 00000000`00000000 00000000`11111000 00000000`00000060 : nvlddmkm+0x47462b
fffff802`1bca3360 fffff802`31df5664 : fffff802`1bca3500 ffff8504`913e7000 fffff802`1bca3500 ffff8504`91487158 : nvlddmkm+0x4737d1
fffff802`1bca3420 fffff802`31df512b : fffff802`1bca3500 ffff8504`91174d30 ffff8504`913e7000 00000000`00000000 : nvlddmkm+0x6d5664
fffff802`1bca3450 fffff802`31df5206 : ffff8504`910ae7a0 ffff8504`91174d30 fffff802`1bca35b0 ffff8504`910ae7a0 : nvlddmkm+0x6d512b
fffff802`1bca34c0 fffff802`31d503d2 : 00000000`00000000 fffff802`1bca35b0 ffffffff`ffffffff fffff802`1bca3640 : nvlddmkm+0x6d5206
fffff802`1bca3530 fffff802`31d500a2 : ffff8504`8f7cc9a0 00000000`00000014 ffff8504`913e7000 00000000`00000000 : nvlddmkm+0x6303d2
fffff802`1bca3570 fffff802`318e0ec9 : 00000000`00000000 fffff802`318f2970 ffff8504`00000000 ffff8504`913e7000 : nvlddmkm+0x6300a2
fffff802`1bca3750 fffff802`31df570c : 00000000`00000000 ffff8504`910ae7a0 ffff8504`913e7000 ffff8504`91487001 : nvlddmkm+0x1c0ec9
fffff802`1bca37a0 fffff802`31b56002 : ffff8504`910ae7a0 ffff8504`913e7000 ffff8504`913e7000 ffff8504`91487000 : nvlddmkm+0x6d570c
fffff802`1bca3810 fffff802`31ab1ac3 : ffff8504`91487000 ffff8504`913f0420 00000000`00000000 ffff8504`913e7000 : nvlddmkm+0x436002
fffff802`1bca3850 fffff802`31ab128a : ffff8504`913e7000 ffff8504`913e7000 ffff8504`913f0420 fffff802`3190cbef : nvlddmkm+0x391ac3
fffff802`1bca38c0 fffff802`31ab1497 : ffff8504`9eb57220 ffff8504`00000018 ffff8504`913e7000 ffff8504`910f2510 : nvlddmkm+0x39128a
fffff802`1bca3910 fffff802`31ab213e : ffff8504`913e8290 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffff802`318f5638 : nvlddmkm+0x391497
fffff802`1bca3990 fffff802`31c9f8d0 : 0000004c`14bfbea8 0000004c`14bfbea8 ffff8504`913e7000 ffff8504`913f0420 : nvlddmkm+0x39213e
fffff802`1bca39f0 fffff802`318cf50a : ffff8504`913e7000 ffff8504`913f0420 ffff8504`8ca30000 fffff802`1b11bf01 : nvlddmkm+0x57f8d0
fffff802`1bca3a20 fffff802`17c6b065 : fffff802`136a6f80 ffff8504`8ae0b000 ffff8504`911f43e0 fffff802`136a4180 : nvlddmkm+0x1af50a
fffff802`1bca3c40 fffff802`17c6a6bf : fffff802`136a4180 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000025 : nt!KiExecuteAllDpcs+0x305
fffff802`1bca3d80 fffff802`17dc80e5 : 00000000`00000000 fffff802`136a4180 ffff9680`8facedc0 ffff8504`8f255000 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x1ef
fffff802`1bca3fb0 fffff802`17dc7ed0 : 00000000`00000000 fffff802`17b602cb 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KxRetireDpcList+0x5
fffff909`1dc17200 fffff802`17dc7785 : ffff8504`8f255000 fffff802`17dc2c01 00000000`00000000 fffff909`1dc172c0 : nt!KiDispatchInterruptContinue
fffff909`1dc17230 fffff802`17dc2c01 : 00000000`00000000 fffff909`1dc172c0 ffff9680`8facedc0 fffff909`0003910c : nt!KiDpcInterruptBypass+0x25
fffff909`1dc17240 fffff802`317d61d8 : fffff802`3182bb48 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000010 01000000`00000000 : nt!KiInterruptDispatch+0xb1
fffff909`1dc173d8 fffff802`3182bb48 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000010 01000000`00000000 fffff909`1dc174e0 : nvlddmkm+0xb61d8
fffff909`1dc173e0 fffff802`3182b10a : ffff8504`8f255000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nvlddmkm+0x10bb48
fffff909`1dc17530 fffff802`322bad34 : ffff8504`8f255000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`ffffffff : nvlddmkm+0x10b10a
fffff909`1dc17580 fffff802`2da5ecd6 : fffff802`322bac75 00000000`00000001 ffff8504`8f255000 00000000`00000000 : nvlddmkm+0xb9ad34
fffff909`1dc17630 fffff802`2da5e487 : 00000000`00000020 fffff909`1dc176f1 00000000`00000000 fffff802`00000000 : dxgkrnl!DpiDxgkDdiSetPowerState+0x5a
fffff909`1dc17690 fffff802`2da5f141 : ffff8504`8f7669a0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 : dxgkrnl!DpiFdoSetAdapterPowerState+0x163
fffff909`1dc17750 fffff802`2da5e810 : fffff909`1dc17700 00000000`00000008 ffff8504`8f766b90 ffff8504`8f7669a0 : dxgkrnl!DpiFdoHandleDevicePower+0x2e1
fffff909`1dc177f0 fffff802`2da5f8e1 : ffff8504`8f7669a0 ffff8504`8f27f180 ffff8504`8f27f030 00000000`ff030000 : dxgkrnl!DpiFdoDispatchPower+0x20
fffff909`1dc17820 fffff802`318826fd : 00000000`00000001 ffff8504`91643000 00000000`00000001 ffff8504`8f7669a0 : dxgkrnl!DpiDispatchPower+0xe1
fffff909`1dc17940 fffff802`3188198e : ffff8504`8f27f030 00000000`00000001 ffff8504`8f7669a0 00000000`00000000 : nvlddmkm+0x1626fd
fffff909`1dc17a30 fffff802`17d7a3bf : ffff8504`8f27f030 fffff909`1dc17ae0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nvlddmkm+0x16198e
fffff909`1dc17a60 fffff802`17d2a715 : 00000000`00000000 ffff8504`8aad1040 fffff802`17d7a1e0 00000000`00000000 : nt!PopIrpWorker+0x1df
fffff909`1dc17b10 fffff802`17dc86ea : ffff9680`8f3c5180 ffff8504`8aad1040 fffff802`17d2a6c0 00000000`00000000 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x55
fffff909`1dc17b60 00000000`00000000 : fffff909`1dc18000 fffff909`1dc11000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x2a


STACK_COMMAND:  .thread 0xffff85048aad1040 ; kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  dca75c22d190cd6f06af0401fd1881161b5680cb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  e16074524b9b7492245f46ab335077c333755967

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  410d646b5b31e3426baec1b12cf2bb0ab383e6f1

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nvlddmkm+1cc9e0
fffff802`318ec9e0 48ff6078        jmp     qword ptr [rax+78h]

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  7860ff48

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  nvlddmkm+1cc9e0

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nvlddmkm

IMAGE_NAME:  nvlddmkm.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5ccfa0fe

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  1cc9e0

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_STACKPTR_ERROR_nvlddmkm!unknown_function

BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_STACKPTR_ERROR_nvlddmkm!unknown_function

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x9F_3_STACKPTR_ERROR_nvlddmkm!unknown_function

TARGET_TIME:  2019-09-16T14:48:01.000Z

OSBUILD:  18362

OSSERVICEPACK:  0

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  unknown_date

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  190318-1202

BUILDLAB_STR:  19h1_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  4473

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_stackptr_error_nvlddmkm!unknown_function

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {8a514180-b6e9-8eb3-31fd-edab360f2285}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

6: kd> dt nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER fffff9091dc7f7b0
Symbol nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER not found.
6: kd> dt nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER fffff9091dc7f7b0
Symbol nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER not found.
6: kd> dt fffff9091dc7f7b0
Symbol not found at address fffff9091dc7f7b0.
6: kd> lmvm pci
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
fffff802`1a7c0000 fffff802`1a82f000   pci        (deferred)             
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\pci.sys
    Image name: pci.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Image was built with /Brepro flag.
    Timestamp:        D78389FA (This is a reproducible build file hash, not a timestamp)
    CheckSum:         0006CC67
    ImageSize:        0006F000
    File version:     10.0.18362.329
    Product version:  10.0.18362.329
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    Information from resource tables:
        CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
        ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
        InternalName:     pci.sys
        OriginalFilename: pci.sys
        ProductVersion:   10.0.18362.329
        FileVersion:      10.0.18362.329 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
        FileDescription:  NT Plug and Play PCI Enumerator
        LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
6: kd> !poaction
PopAction: fffff80218044080
  State..........: 0 - Idle
  Updates........: 0 
  Action.........: None
  Lightest State.: Unspecified
  Flags..........: 10000003 QueryApps|UIAllowed
  Irp minor......: ??
  System State...: Unspecified
  Hiber Context..: 0000000000000000

Allocated power irps (PopIrpList - fffff802180447d0)
  IRP: ffff85048ae166f0 (wait-wake/S3), PDO: ffff85048c99c670
  IRP: ffff85048ae15490 (wait-wake/S3), PDO: ffff85048aacb060
  IRP: ffff850490d8a9e0 (wait-wake/S0), PDO: ffff85048c93bd40
  IRP: ffff85048f77c050 (wait-wake/S4), PDO: ffff85048f7240a0
  IRP: ffff85048f770010 (wait-wake/S4), PDO: ffff85048f780060
  IRP: ffff85048f7bd010 (wait-wake/S4), PDO: ffff85048f78b110
  IRP: ffff85048f7669a0 (set/D0,), PDO: ffff85048ca4e570, CURRENT: ffff85048f27f030

Irp worker threads (PopIrpThreadList - fffff80218039d90)
  THREAD: ffff85048ab03040 (static)
  THREAD: ffff85048aad1040 (static), IRP: ffff85048f7669a0, DEVICE: ffff85048f27f030

Broadcast in progress: FALSE
Is Directed DRIPS Transition: FALSE

No Device State present

6: kd> !irp ffff85048f7669a0
Irp is active with 6 stacks 5 is current (= 0xffff85048f766b90)
 No Mdl: No System Buffer: Thread 00000000:  Irp stack trace.  Pending has been returned
     cmd  flg cl Device   File     Completion-Context
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_WAIT_WAKE(0)]
            0  0 ffff85048ca4e570 00000000 fffff8022d92ded0-fffff9091dc17790    
           \Driver\pci  dxgkrnl!DpiFdoPowerCompletionRoutine
            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>[IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffff85048f27f030 00000000 fffff80217d6ff80-ffff850491a386a8 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\nvlddmkm nt!PopRequestCompletion
            Args: 00000000 00000001 00000001 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-ffff850491a386a8    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
6: kd> !devstack ffff85048ca4e570
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffff85048f27f030  \Driver\nvlddmkm   ffff85048f27f180  
  ffff85048aace040  \Driver\ACPI       ffff85048c3e83f0  
> ffff85048ca4e570  \Driver\pci        ffff85048ca4e6c0  NTPNP_PCI0014
!DevNode ffff85048ca4f010 :
  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1C8C&SUBSYS_850A1558&REV_A1\4&23726a3e&0&0008"
  ServiceName is "nvlddmkm"
```

Since I'm new to debug Windows I don't know how to analyze it.
But I guess "nvlddmkm" is making the BSOD. Am I right?

I need some advice from you.

Comment: More than likely it is that driver causing it.

Comment: @Moab I'm using a NVIDIA graphic driver, NVIDIA GeForce GTX1050 Ti v26.21.14.3064. It was built on 2019-05-05.

Comment: @mazend Then try updating the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Yup. I've updated the NVIDIA driver and it seems the issue resolved. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash is happening in `dxgkrnl`, which is the DirectX Graphics Kernel that
handles anything related to multimedia or video.
So perhaps the problem is video-oriented.

Some steps that might help:

- Download and install the
  [NVIDIA driver for the GeForce GTX1050 Ti](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/151275/en-us).
- Run the [DirectX Diagnostic Tool](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/diagnose-and-troubleshoot-basic-problems-with-directx)
- [Update or re-install DirectX](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/directx-11-download-update-install)
- Check Windows integrity using
  [SFC and DISM](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
- Run the
  [Blue Screen Troubleshooter](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-10-blue-screen-troubleshooter)
- Turn off NVIDIA Surround in the NVIDIA Control Panel, in
  *3D Settings > Configure Surround, PhysX*, under the section of
  Surround Configuration, uncheck the option labeled as "Span displays with Surround",
  click on OK and reboot.
  (If you don't have that option then it does not apply to your card.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

1. I've downloaded the latest driver NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti v26.21.14.3630 built on 2019-09-05.
2. I've run DirectX Diagnostic Tool but I can't find problems here.
3. DirectX was the latest version so I didn't re-install.
4. I can't using SFC and DISM since what file is wrong.
5. It seems lite the Blue Screen Troubleshooter is obsolete.
6. The settings was already turned off.

I need time to check whether the problem happens or not.

Comment: I've checked my laptop for 2 days and the issue didn't happen. It seems the issue was resolved after updating the NVIDIA driver.

Comment: I had updated the NVIDIA driver maybe 1 year ago but then the issue was not resolved...I'm not sure why the issue was resolved this time. Anyways I'm happy to resolve the issue. Thank you again.